# jmeter run same HTTP Request on multiple servers

Tags: http, request, jmeter

I am trying to have jmeter run the same exact tests (same threads, assertions, etc.) on multiple servers, is it possible to do this without defining seperate HTTP Request objects for each one? I have tried setting up multiple HTTP Config elements but this does not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Easiest and functional way is to set CSV file with list of hosts you want to run the tests on, then use CSV Data Set Config (Add -> Config Element) to load this file and set a variable name to something like hostname or whatever. Then add HTTP Request Defaults element and set 'Servername or IP' to that ${hostname} and you pretty much set-up. Now you just need to set Thread Group's 'Number of Threads' to the number of hosts you are trying to check so it will add a different variable from the file to each thread.

The only thing you have to remember is to put your CSV Data Set Config before the requests, at the beginning of the thread or (if you want to use it with larger name of threads) before the Thread Groups. And of course to change the number of threads to run it for each host/IP.

I've tested it a minute ago and it works for sure.

Comment: well if you load each servername from the csv file in vars , like server1,server2,server3 and so on how you do want to use it with the HTTP Request defaults.. you can only use one of them.. and you need to use all of them!

Comment: You're not loading those hostnames in different vars, you have csv file with column starting with var name and each row is loaded as value of that variable for separate thread. Probably it can be used in loop as well.

Comment: I think I've figured out what I have been doing wrong, I loaded the hosts in one line l.e: host1, host2,host3 while to get this working you have to do it in separate 3 lines like: server,host1 \n  server,host2 \n server,host3 \n... where \n is just line break

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to say. Maybe it wasn't clear enough.